# Is __autoload() called for parent classes of autoloaded classes?

Tags: php, inheritance, autoload

In `main.php`, autoload is added and a new object is created:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    require_once($class . '.php');
}
...
$t = new Triangle($side1, $side2, $side3);
```

In `Triangle.php`:

```
class Triangle extends Shape {...}
```

`Shape.php` is an abstract class:

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract protected function get_area();
    abstract protected function get_perimeter();
}
```

I can see that `__autoload` function calls `Triangle.php`, but does it call `Shape.php` at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No (not at the *exact* same time), but yes (it will get loaded and everything will work).

When you call `new Triangle` it will see that Triangle is a class which hasn't been loaded yet, so it calls `__autoload()`. This will then `require_once` the Triangle.php file.

In parsing Triangle.php it sees that there's another class which hasn't been loaded (Shape) so it repeats the process.

In short, there's nothing more you need to do than what you've got, but it does it in a number of passes.

Comment: +1 But omitting the parenthesis (which are comments), your first sentence reads `"no, but yes"` :)

Comment: hehe yeah - 'twas on purpose. "No" was answering exactly what was asked, "yes" was answering what I figured was meant.

Answer (score 2):

It should, yes. I guess you could verify that by simply adding an

```
echo "loaded $class!\n";
```

statement to your __autoload handler?

Answer (score 1):

autoload is executed every time a class definiton can not be found.

In your case it will first be called for Triangle, then the parser encounters reference to Shape in Triangle.php and will then autoload Shape.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($class) {
    print "autoloading $class\n";
    require_once($class . '.php');
}

$t = new Triangle();

[~]> php test.php 
autoloading Triangle
autoloading Shape
```