# PHP Autoloading Extended Classes

Tags: php, oop, spl-autoload-register

Based on the response from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420174/is-autoload-called-for-parent-classes-of-autoloaded-classes) I would expect my code to work but for some reason it is not. I have a simple class that extends a class from my library of classes.

**_custom.php**

```
$custom = new MyClass();
class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass{

  public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
  }

}
```

Unfortunately I get this fatal error:

> **Fatal error**: Class 'MyClass' not found in ...

But if I remove the `extends MyAbstractClass` then the error goes away. It seems the issue is that when attempting to extend the class, it does not attempt to load `MyAbstactClass` which then causes `MyClass` to not be found at all.

Any thoughts or suggestions on this?

Comment: Are you sure the error goes away or does a cooler/harder to debug one show up?

Comment: Also you need to show autoloader code

Comment: When I remove the extends than `MyClass` autoloads as expected...

Comment: If you do `$custom = new MyClass();` after the declaration of your class? When you try to load it, the class is not defined yet. I mean if the code is exactly as it is in your question. not sure that is an autoload problem.

Comment: where are you loading MyAbstractClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is an interpreted language, meaning that what is *known* for PHP to define is the code that parsed before a statement.

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass{

  public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct(); #you are forcing a construct call, it is not required if the parent constructor has no args.
  }

}

$custom = new MyClass();
```

With classes you can prevent this behavior by using an autoloader, when an object is called and is undefined, it will try to *inject* and parse the class by your given code.

You can define the magic function [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) but the [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is preferred as it is more dynamic and not a constant as the `__autoload()` function is.

Comment: I guess I found it strange that prior to using `spl_autoload_register()` putting it in that order worked, and in this current refactor I implemented autoloading and now the order was affected. It is working now though so that's all that matters. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It would have worked *IF* you included the file that contained the class name. Personally I use the PS4 autoload class, modified it to make it more efficient. It includes a class by namespace, also defines which folder it is in. So if I `use \lib\db\statement` from within a class, it will attempt to load "statement.php" from my "webroot\lib\db\" directory.